# Intent filter to open my application when a specific URL is called is not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter

I am trying to use an intent filter to open my activity if a certain URL is opened, whether from a scanned QR code, a link in an email or from browsing to the site from Chrome or the browser. Here is a snippet from my Manifest:

> ```
>  <activity
>         android:name="com.openapp.projecttest.Main"
>         android:label="@string/app_name" >
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
> ```

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter> 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
            <data android:host="www.qwert.com" android:scheme="http"></data> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </activity>
```

When I browse to it on Google Chrome, it does not seem to trigger the intent filter. Am I missing a permission?

Comment: Does the URL you are using contain paths in it? like www.qwert.com/somePath

Comment: Could you provide an example of the URL you're trying to trigger the filter with?

Comment: It was not working for any URL, but I have come to a realisation that it does now work from a link, but does not work if I browse to the URL through the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work from a link, but does not work if browsed to the URL through the browser.

Answer (score 0):

It should work through a browser link if you include the pathPattern in your data filter.

```
android:pathPattern="/path/pattern"
```

where you fill in the path and pattern, of course.

Comment: It does work through a link, I was interested in getting it to work if  you browse to the link via the URL on the browser